# Error: Left hand side of assignment must be a variable

Tags: if-statement

I don't see why I'm getting the error, "The left hand side of the assignment must be a variable" in the else if condition. Ideas?

Code:

```
    if (getInput > 1 && getInput < 5000);{
    System.out.println("LOWER");
    System.out.println("Please enter a value between 1 and 4999:");
    }
    else if (getInput > 1 && getInput < 4999); {
    System.out.println("HIGHER");
    System.out.println("Please enter a value between 501 and 4999:");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolons after the test conditions.

if (getInput > 1 && getInput < 5000);{

should be

if (getInput > 1 && getInput < 5000){

and

else if (getInput > 1 && getInput < 4999); {

should be

else if (getInput > 1 && getInput < 4999) {